# Calculate a limit $\lim_{t\to 0} \Big(\frac{a_1^t+a_2^t+...+a_n^t}{n}\Big)^{1/t}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Calculate a limit

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \Big(\frac{a_1^t+a_2^t+...+a_n^t}{n}\Big)^{1/t}$$

$a_i \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$

I may guess a usage of squeeze theorem like

$a_{min}$ and $a_{max}$ exist so

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \Big(\frac{na_{min}^t}{n}\Big)^{1/t} = \lim_{t\to 0} a_{min}$$

and

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \Big(\frac{na_{max}^t}{n}\Big)^{1/t} = \lim_{t\to 0} a_{max}$$

but $\lim_{t \to 0}  a_{min}$ is not the same as for $a_{max}$. So I stuck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Taylor expansion $a^t = e^{\log(a)t} = 1 + \log(a) t+ O(t^2)$ to get

$$\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_i^t}{n}\right)^{1/t} = \left(1 + \frac{\log(a_1a_2\ldots a_n) t}{n} + O(t^2)\right)^{1/t}$$

which can be evaluated using the known limit $e^x = \lim\limits_{t\to 0}(1+xt)^{1/t}$.